# Can a saddle clamp be upside down on a children's bike?

Tags: saddle, children

Generally, when we put a saddle clamp on we put it so the rails are mounted on the "top" side (reference clamp pictured):

[image]

However in my case I still need to lower a seat by a inch more.  Looking at the clamp I could do this:

[image]

I'm asking this for my kids 16" bike.  She fits the bike well, but has a little issue of getting up on the saddle.  There appears to be enough space in the saddle to flip the clamp.  She is on the petite side at 15kg (and for reference, same model bike, my son was 23kg when he retired it).  I do plan on flipping it back over before I extend the seat post though.

Does this work or will I run into issues?

I went ahead and did it, it was just right amount she needed, didn't even mess with the lock on the rack.

[image]

*EDIT*

Not to take away on the answers here.  My daughter has been riding this bike like this for just under a year now.  She has even taken it off a simple 2x4 and plywood ramp without issue.  I'm sure it will handle most kids, but since she is on the small side then I can't really answer as such.

Comment: Generally if the frame is so big that you have to slam the seat all the way down, then the frame is too big for you.  On older bikes the seat is usually much closer to the frame, but you shouldn't really need to put it down so close to the frame. If you can't stand over the top tube, flat footed, then it's probably too big.

Comment: Most saddles on a road bike won't give you another inch even if you did that -- the point in the front will hit the top tube. And if you're worried about needing an inch on a mountain bike, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: I doubt your saddle has room inside to fit the bulk of the clamp mechanism above the rails.   Consider getting a single-bolt hockey stick seatpost instead.

Comment: Don't worry, this is for a 16" pretty pink bike.  She just has a award time getting on it.  There is room to flip it over, I'll give it a few days to see how it goes.

Comment: You never said it was for a lightweight kid.  Probably okay if she's light enough, but do make this the first thing to revert as she grows.    As for problems getting on/off, make sure the standover height is not too high.  Could be she needs another 6-12 months growth to fit this bike.

Comment: Try it and see if it works.  The clamp is plenty strong.  The only real issue is whether there's clearance below the seat.  (This is not to say that this is a good idea from a bike fit standpoint -- if the seat needs to be that low then likely the frame is too big in several other aspects.)

Comment: I wanted this to be more generic, but considering this is for a girl in the early years of riding, then I'll rephrase this to make it more clear.  I just built my daughter a 16" bike though since she out grew her 12".  The only problem is that between herself and the saddle height, getting up on it is tricky.  She was doing fine on my son's bike (same model, bike star 16" step-through), but his had the tires replaced (2.1" -> 1.75") and the seat is probably compressed.

Comment: Late thought - there's often a lip on the "top" of the clamp where the seat post goes in, to stop it dropping down too far.   You'll want to disassemble the clamp and keep that bit the same, while rotating the rail grabbing bits,

Comment: This clamp does have that lip.  With as tight as that clamp was on there this should work well.  It was on there so tight, I bet I don't need the bolt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself which is stronger.  In the correct orientation a downward force would need to sheer the bolt to come out the bottom.  In the incorrect orientation a downward force just needs squeeze through the gap (bend a relatively thin plate just a fraction).  It is not designed to take force in the that direction.

And you have to consider stand over. If you get the seat low enough then your stand over will go negative.  Even if flipping worked you are going to be close or into a negative stand over.

And need room in the seat to be flipped.

Have you even tried this?

Oh, this is for light child? Light child is not likely to break a seat clamp even in a compromised orientation. Kids are not disposable but they are hard to break. Even if (**and that is a big if**) the rail blew out one side it is not even likely a trip to the hospital. A blow out to the front tire is more likely and will have the same scraped knee and tears.